# LESS imports not working when bundled using Extract Text plugin for Webpack

Tags: css, less, webpack

I have been playing about with less in development just fine, but for some reason when I bundle it for production using the Extract Text Plugin, the import functionality doesn't work.

For the `index.less` file below:

```
@import 'global-styles/variables.less';

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  font-family: @font-family;
  font-weight: @headings-font-weight;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Module build failed: variable @font-family is undefined
 @ /Users/mattdalton/WebStorm Projects/react-comments/client/src/index.less        (line 5, column 15)
 near lines:
   .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
     font-family: @font-family;
     font-weight: @headings-font-weight;
```

I have bundled this using the following Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  bail: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    path.join(paths.appSrc, 'index')
  ],
  output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', ''],
    alias: {
       'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    }
  },
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: require('./babel.prod')
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?-autoprefixer!postcss')
  },
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?-autoprefixer!postcss!less')
  },
 //.....
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', 
        ]
      }),
    ];
  },
  plugins: [
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true
      }
     }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true, 
        warnings: false
     },
      mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        screw_ie8: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css')
  ]
};
```

I have tried this with a few different component less files and I have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, I don't have a direct answer to the question, however I did solve it by just switching to sass.

I installed `sass-loader` and `node-sass`, changed the filenames to `.scss`, then simply changed my variables to sass syntax (i.e. $ rather than @). Once I changed `less` to `sass` in webpack everything worked. I can only assume there was a problem in less-loader or its compatibility with another loader.

Might be useful to someone having the same issue - SASS seems better supported in Webpack/React-land anyway, so making the switch might be a good idea if it's possible for you.